# HDFS: Actual space of all disks on cluster vs usable HDFS size

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, bigdata

How can I calculate the available size of an HDFS cluster based on the total size of disks in the cluster?

E.g. If my cluster is 10 machines, each with 1TB of storage, what will `hadoop fs -df` report?

More specifically, I need to store 5 TB of data in an HDFS cluster. How much total disk space does my cluster need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That all Depends on how you set your HDFS replication factor.
The default (and recommended) is 3.

You can also set hdfs to keep some non-dfs space so, substract that if need be.

A rough calculation is almost always `file size * 3 = total storage needed`.

Comment: OK great thanks. I'll disable replication since I'm using ephemeral clusters.

Comment: That's ill advised. You risk losing data if a node dies.
Also, you ll have data of any block only on 1 node at a time. So potentially more data has to be streamed from all nodes to a node running a job.

Comment: Good point re data locality. I'm not bothered about losing data since this is a copy anyway. I'll increase it to 2.